# drag and drop while keeping copy of dragged element

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I want to drag and drop input elements from one div to another div while keeping the copy of dragged element in parent div.i achieve this.but after dropping
 into droppable div still it is performing drag and drop function.and
 allowing to make multiple copy also.but i don’t want this.. how this
 can be avoid in droppable div.

```
           function allowDrop(ev)
                    {
                        ev.preventDefault();
                    }  //alert("droped");  //alert("droped");

                    function drag(ev) 
                    {
                      //alert("dragging");
                        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
                    }

                    function drop(ev)
                    {             
                        var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
                        ev.preventDefault();
    }

html page:

    <div id="drag1"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >
<div id="drag1"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >

            <div class="drag"  onclick='return false;'readonly>
            <label>
                textbox</label><input  type="text" name="text" value="">
            </div>
        </div><br>

        <div id="drag2" class="drag" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >
            <div onclick='return false;'>
                <input type="radio" name="" value=""><label>check button</label><br>
            </div> <br>
        </div>

        <div id="drag3" class="drag" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="" value=""><label>check box</label><br>
            </div> 
        </div><br>
```

Comment: please friends help me to find a solution

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?